# Cannot pull image from remote Gitlab registry to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I've been trying to create a deployment of docker image to Kubernetes cluster without luck, my deployment.yaml looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: application-deployment
  labels:
    app: application
spec:
  serviceAccountName: gitlab
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
  - name: application
    image: example.org:port1/foo/bar:latest
    ports:
      - containerPort: port2
  volumes:
    - name: foo
      secret:
        secretName: regcred
```

But it fails to get the image.

> Failed to pull image "example.org:port1/foo/bar:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://example.org:port1/v2/foo/bar/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden

The secret used in `deployment.yaml`, was created like this:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=${CI_REGISTRY} --docker-username=${CI_REGISTRY_USER} --docker-password=${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} --docker-email=${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}
```

**Attempt #1: adding imagePullSecrets**

```
...
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

results in:

> Failed to pull image "example.org:port1/foo/bar:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://example.org:port1/v2/foo/bar/manifests/latest: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied

**Solution:**

I've created deploy token under *Settings > Repository > Deploy Tokens > (created one with read_registry scope)*

And added given values to environment variables and an appropriate line now looks like:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=${CI_REGISTRY} --docker-username=${CI_DEPLOY_USER} --docker-password=${CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}
```

I've got the problematic line from tutorials & Gitlab docs, where they've described deploy tokens but further used problematic line in examples.

Comment: seems like you are missing an imagePullSecret. Check out this page to see how to pull an image from a private registry 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: @relief.melone results in a bit different error. The last part changes in `unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied`

Comment: When creating the secret did you enter your gitlab password or personal token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced your issue and the problem is with password you used while creating a repository's secret. When creating a secret for gitlab repository you have to use personal token created in gitlab instead of a password.

You can create a token by going to `Settings -> Access Tokens`. Then you have to pick a name for your token, expiration date and token's scope.

Then create a secret as previously by running

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=$docker_server --docker-username=$docker_username --docker-password=$personal_token
```

While creating a pod you have to include

```
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Comment: Indeed, wrong authentication. Access token isn't the most appropriate in my case so I've created deploy token.

Answer (score 3):

You need add the imagePullSecret on your deployment, so your pod will be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: application-deployment
  labels:
    app: application
spec:
  serviceAccountName: gitlab
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
  - name: application
    image: example.org:port1/foo/bar:latest
    ports:
      - containerPort: port2
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Be sure that the secret and pod is running on same namespace.

Also make sure that the container you are pulling exist and with the right tag.

I notice you are trying to run the command on pipeline on gitlab-ci, check after run the create secret command that your secret is right (with the variables replacement).

You can verify if you can login to registry and pull the image manually on some other linux to by sure that the credentials are right.

Comment: Have already tried and results in different error as described in question and comments. I've tested `regcred` as described in [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#inspecting-the-secret-regcred).

Comment: I read the comment but, the error "unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied" leads to incorrect credentials or no permissions to the resource. Sorry by be insistent, but did you the verifies about credentials and grants? Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

creating a secret didn't work for me at first, though I had to specify the namespace for the secret and it worked.

```
kubectl delete secret -n ${NAMESPACE} regcred --ignore-not-found
kubectl create secret -n ${NAMESPACE} docker-registry regcred --docker-server=${CI_REGISTRY} --docker-username=${CI_DEPLOY_USERNAME} --docker-password=${CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD} --docker-email=${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}
```